# Rspec; Assert new window URL string

Tags: url, rspec, watir-webdriver, assertion

I would like to put together an assertion that, when I open a new window, asserts that the URL now includes `?preview=true` 
What I have so far:

```
p @browser.url.include? '?preview=true'
```

However, when I go to run this, it always returns false. 
If I run

```
p @browser.url
```

It reads the url correctly (including, obviously, the "?preview=true" part of the string)

Is there a method I'm missing for reading *part* of a url string?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you using [`.use`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Window#use-instance_method) to "attach" to the spawned window?

Comment: @orde, yes I made sure to use `.use`.  That was part of why I ran an initial test using `p @browser.url` so I was sure I was reading the proper information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. For the Rspec assertion, you should be able to try something like this for the partial url:

```
@browser.url.should include('?preview=true')
```

You can also do the following for the full url:

```
@browser.url.should == "google.com"
```

Comment: your thoughts on the assertion are similar to what I ended up using.  Note: `should` is considered deprecated syntax (from what I understand), and I wrote my assertion like this: `expect(@browser.url).to include('?preview=true')`

Comment: Ah, that's right. It is deprecated. Glad that solution helped.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you might have a timing issue, potentially the check is being made before the URL is updated.

I tested this manually just now using IRB to be sure it should work, and as far as I can tell, it ought to.

```
$irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'watir-webdriver'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x..f7db893ba0a186b8 url="data:," title="">
irb(main):003:0> b.goto 'http://google.com'
=> "http://google.com"
irb(main):004:0> puts b.url
https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> puts b.url.include? '?gws_rd'
true
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> puts b.url.include? '?gws_rd=ssl'
true
=> nil
irb(main):007:0>
```

You might need to add some kind of sync point, such as waiting for an element that would appear on the page as a result of local JS code (e.g. after an ajax call) but is not there when the browser reports the page is 'loaded'

You can probably test this by inserting a tiny debugging loop at the point where you are trying to check the URL to see if it starts out one thing and changes to another.

```
50.times do
  puts @browser.url
  sleep 0.1
end
```